# Hex Decode using php

Tags: php, hex

I would like to know where I can find a function in php that performs the decoding of this type of encoding in hex.
http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/?results=61292a2c593c3b93bf8d1e6d10c94e05
Using function in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a decoder. PHP recognizes hex escapes in its string literals similarly to JavaScript. So just put the strings into a PHP script and print them.

```
$encoded = ["\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x43\x6F\x6E\x74\x61\x69\x6E\x65\x72","\x41\x6E\x56\x2D\x30\x34"];
var_dump($encoded);
```

prints:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "videoContainer"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "AnV-04"
}
```